# Minesweeper countdown timer

Tags: java, timer, java-threads, minesweeper

I am having difficulty with a timer for Minesweeper. timeLabel is a Jlabel for the allowed time remaining in the level, and time is the allowed time (in seconds). The problem is, whenever I restart the game, it will speed up the timer. Does calling the method again when I restart cause this? And what can I do to fix this?

```
public void addTimer(int t){
    time = t;
    countDown = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(time >= 0){
                timeLabel.setText(time + "");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    }
                time -= 1;
            }
        }
    };
    countDown.start();
}
```

Comment: You need to kill the old thread before restarting. After a restart you will have two countdown threads running (both decrementing `time`). I think. Can't be sure without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: Your timer is likely still running, and then when you restart the game, you have it run a second time on top of the first. Don't do that. But also importantly, yours is a Swing program, and your code breaks Swing threading rules -- you're mutating the state of a JLabel, your timeLabel **off** of the Swing event thread, and this can set you up for hard to debug intermitting threading exceptions. Instead you should use a Swing Timer for Swing GUI's.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've done a little [minesweeper Swing coding myself](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a522444%20minesweeper). Please check out the link.

Comment: @name Thank you, that fixed it